# How to access REST service in Actionscript 3?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, rest

I have write a api service at 'http://localhost:3000/api/user/id', do a GET, can get a JSON response.

How to access this service from actionscript3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a simple `URLRequest`:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

try
{
    loader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost:3000/api/user/id"));
}
catch (error:Error)
{
    trace("Error loading URL: " + error.message);
}

function loaderCompleteHandler(e:Event):void
{
    // and here's your response (in your case the JSON)
    trace(e.target.data);
}

function httpStatusHandler(e:HTTPStatusEvent):void
{
    trace("httpStatusHandler:" + e.status);
}

function securityErrorHandler(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("securityErrorHandler:" + e.text);
}

function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + e.text);
}
```

Comment: No you can't - this will only allow for GET and POST requests, but not for the other HTTP request methods, which you need for a complete REST service.

Comment: That's true, the questioner asked for a way to get the GET response. So in that case this answer is sufficient.

Comment: OK, I give you that.  If it isn't enough, OP should have been more specific.

Comment: Ah... what's the special about del and put method?