# REST interface method POST in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, rest

I have to make a game for my thesis. I'm coding in ActionScript3. I have to use a service (REST interface). I've already read something about doing a GET.

[How to access REST service in Actionscript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180515/how-to-access-rest-service-in-actionscript-3)

Someone wrote that this code could be also use to do a POST, but how would the code change? How to do a POST from ActionScript3? Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change the method of the `URLRequest` object. By default, it uses GET.

```
var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest( URL );
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; //this sets it to POST instead of GET
l.load( req );
```

See [`URLRequest.method`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#method) in the LiveDocs

Comment: I would give you a point, but I have no reputation because I'm new! Thank you a lot!

Comment: If this answered the question, you should mark it as correct (click the checkmark under the number) to close it. This will also help you build reputation and allow you to vote sooner

Comment: See [`URLRequest.data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you configure the `URLRequest` differently:

```
var request = new URLRequest("http://localhost:3000/api/user/id");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST
loader.load(request);
```

see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#method for more.

Comment: I would give you a point, but I have no reputation because I'm new! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The key is the URLRequest, and the `method` property.  Leveraging from the example you referenced, modify the code to be

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:3000/api/user/id");
req.method = "POST"'
loader.load(req);
```

Comment: Oops, missed that there were already the same answers already posted...  :-)

Comment: I would give you a point, but I have no reputation because I'm new! Thank you a lot!